# How do I convert a YYYYMMDD decimal to date in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to convert an integer to a date or a date to an integer so I can compare two columns. I'm using teradata and have been struggling with Invalid Date [Error 2665] when trying to cast either to the other format. The formats are:

```
20220830 Type D
2022-08-05 Type DA
```

Methods I've tried:

```
SELECT cast((20220830 - 19000000) as date)
SELECT CAST(TRIM(20201231) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')
select cast(2022-08-05  as Integer Format '99999999')
Select Convert(DATETIME, LEFT(20130101, 8))
SELECT CAST(CAST(20220830 AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')

select cast(test_date as date format'YYYYMMDD')
from
(SELECT cast (integer_date as char(8)) as test_date
from example)t1
```

Any insights into why these methods aren't working would be a great help

Comment: You can cast to string and then date so you can supply the format: `SELECT CAST(CAST(20220830 AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')`

Comment: @JNevill I tried and still returned same error. With similar logic I tried to cast in a subquery first thinking maybe that would treat it different but didn't work either

Comment: Odd. That one works fine for me. What error do you get when you run that? You can also do this more math-y like `SELECT 20220830 - 19000000(date)`

Comment: @JNevill Thank you that solved it. Needed to see the numeric output first to realize I didn't bracket the parenthesis correctly.

Comment: `TO_DATE` works here  : `to_date(cast(20220830 as char(8)),'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('2022-08-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Answer (score 0):

Select cast((column_name)-19000000 as date). Mistake was in trying to format such as Select cast((column_name)-19000000 as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD)